# How to get information about sensors on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sensors

On iOS, is it possible to get information about the sensors available (like accelerometer, magnetic, light, proximity, gyroscope, etc…)?

Is there any method like getSensorList(), getVendor(), getModel()?

Answer (score 1):

For the accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer, use a [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For the proximity sensor, you can try to set the `proximityMonitoringEnabled` property on the current `UIDevice` to YES.  Then check the `proximityMonitoringEnabled` property.  If its YES, then the device has a proximity monitor, if its NO then it doesn't.

For the 'light', you are most likely interested in whether or not the device has a flash or a torch. [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has the properties you are looking for.